# Are xcode 2x assets possible to use as 3x?

Tags: ios9, iphone-6-plus

I'm building an iPhone app and I made all the designs in the dimensions for iPhone 5 (640x1136px), while I'm almost complete with the app iOS 9 and iPhone 6+ was released and that requires 3x assets. Do I have to re-do all the designs in iPhone 6+ dimensions (1242x2208px) ? I used Photoshop instead of Illustrator.

Comment: You should ask this question at [Graphics Stack Exchange](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) Probably if you are more interested in graphics POV of this. But Your app will still be able to run on iPhone 6+ even though graphics will not be that crisp as you can imagine. So, Do create 3x assets as it is suggested by guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Photoshop you could just edit the image size (Image > Image Size) and resave it as a different name. When resizing the image, enter the new measurements in the Pixel Dimensions area at the top of the Image Size window.

Comment: When resizing a bitmap like this, some artefacts will occur.  The whole point of 3x assets is to provide a better graphics quallity for the end user. What you said make only sense if working with vectors.

Comment: Would that make the assets pixelated when I slice? or would they be 3x perfect resolution?

Comment: Whirlwind does have a point. I **should** have added that for the best result you would need to touch up the image afterward by zooming in and making some corrections. However, even if you didn't, it should be crisper than leaving it as 2x and using it on an iPhone 6+ or 6s+.  Have you checked using a simulator or 6+ how your 2x images look?

Comment: @AliSiam You can't resize bitmap graphics without quallity loss. This is why you should always use ( if possible) vector graphics as a source, and make bitmaps from that vector file. Vector graphics don't loose quallity when resized. Anyways, sometimes differences are not noticeable so much. Depending on how your scene and view are set (as well as scene's scale mode) you can even go only with 2x assets. Search SO about this topic... There are few useful posts.

Comment: Agree totally on all points. I suspect the app will probably look fine with the 2x assets anyway.

Comment: Yeah. It really depends on the actual art. The game from my profile uses only 2x assets (because of a known bug with texture atlases and 3x assets in SpriteKit) , and looks pretty much awesome on 6+. Actually I can hardly see a difference between 6 and 6+.

Comment: I did 2x assets and it looks really weird for some screens on the iPhone6+ simulator. but other screens are hardly noticeable. I guess my only option is what @Monomeeth suggested. Image > Image size > iPhone 6+ dimensions. I learned my lesson now Illustaror is what I need use from now on, I guess its a rookie mistake

Comment: All my layers are in this form http://postimg.org/image/qc4h4oixn/
I think I might make edit to them and still maintain resolution.